# Coredata without using navigation based application

Tags: iphone

I need to use coredata in my View based Application. I created core data file. But I can't access to core data through my Viewbased application without using UITableview.

I used just UITextField and buttons only. I want to need insert records, deletion, updation and search all operations in my application.

Does anyone have some sample code without using navigation based with UITableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = // Your context pointer here
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ObjectName" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
[fetchRequest release];
for (int index=0; index<[objects count]; index++) {
  ObjectName *dmg = (ObjectName *)[menus objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

This will get you your objects out of the Core Data.  You can manipulate this as you see fit as long as you commit it it will be saved in your database.  It sounds like you should also search Stack Overflow (and maybe also a search engine) for information about Predicates, which allow you to filter your object graph.